# Is flush and clear cache the same?

Tags: caching

Is flushing and clearing the cache the same?
How should I I flush the cache?

It seems like the only available option for me is clear cache, but I saw a video tutorial which uses flush cache in Drupal 7. What will I do to avail this option?

Comment: Flush & Clear are the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, the English verbs "flush" and "clear" are equivalent.

However, I've never seen a command named "flush cache" in Drupal 7.  Not having seen the video tutorial you mention, it is impossible to tell what was ment.  In the standard GUI, the button "Clear all caches" (under *Home » Administration » Configuration » Development » Clear cache*) is (AFAIK) the *only* way to do it.

If you have *Drush* installed, you can do more or less the same thing using the CLI with the following command:

```
drush cache-clear all
```

The difference is that the command `drush cache-clear all` also clear its internal cache, and there may be subtle differences because the drush user and web-server user are different, and may therefore interact different with file permissions to caches in the file system, such as the *css* registry.

However, *Drush* also allows you to make more targeted cache clears, see: [Making Targeted Drupal Cache Clears using Drush](http://www.bryanbraun.com/2014/04/07/making-targeted-drupal-cache-clears-using-drush).

Comment: Use `drush cc all` for short

Comment: The confusion likely lies in the fact that `drush cc all` calls `drupal_flush_all_caches()`.  And as a side not, this has changed in Drupal 8...